# Add the ability to retract a reopen vote

Tags: feature-request, voting, vote-to-reopen

When you vote to close a post, you can retract your close vote by re-clicking the "Close" button.  Can we have the ability to do the same with regard to reopen votes?  It should act the same way as if you were retracting a close vote, showing this popup:

[image]

Or add something relevant to reopen votes in that popup, like:

> Are you sure (you cannot vote to reopen again after retracting)?